# How do C++ libraries and frameworks add functionality that is not in the standard library?

Tags: c++, libraries

Do all C++ libraries and frameworks depend on standard libraries and extend functionality which is already in C++? If not how do they add extra functionality to the language?

For example, I read that the C++ standard library doesn't have functions for audio, so how does OpenAL do it?

If all libraries and frameworks depend on standard libraries, is it possible to do everything without any library, with just the standard library and pure C++?

Comment: Technically you don't need the standard libraries to do anything either, it just makes a lot of common requirements much easier.

Comment: How is it possible?

Comment: Those libraries make use of system-specific APIs.  For instance under Linux they can use (non-C++-standard) Unix API functions like `open()`, `write()`, `ioctl()` to open a device file and thus request the operating system to control the hardware appropriately.  OpenAL is, as the name suggests, open-source, so you could read the source code to see what they do.

Comment: If you needed a specific "audio library" to do anything audio related... how would you create that audio library in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

C++ as a language allows you to write any program that you want. That can include writing a program that does nothing by itself, instead providing functions and classes for others to use. That is called a library.

If you couldn't do audio things without an audio library, how would the audio library be written in the first place?

The use of libraries is generally an *economic* choice. It is *often* worthwhile to *not write code* if you can. At the extreme end, if a particular library author has a NDA with a particular hardware vendor, the effort to reverse-engineer how the hardware is controlled could be gigantic compared to using the library that was written with the confidential knowledge.